# An $R$ module is quasi injective if and only if an extension of morphisms holds.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

We say that an $R$-modules $M$ is *quasi-injective* if for every linear monomorphism $f: N \to M$ and every linear morphism $g: N \to M$ there is $h \in End_{R}(M)$ such that $g=hf$. This can be depicted as the following commutativity diagram:

\begin{array}{lll} 0  \rightarrow & N \xrightarrow{f}  & M \\ & \downarrow{g} & \swarrow{h} \\ & M  & \end{array}

I want to prove the following Bland´s Proposition:

An $R$ module is quasi injective if and only if for every pair of submodules $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ of $M$ such that $N_{1} \subset N_{2}$ each $f \in Hom_{R}(N_{1}, M)$ can be extended to a $g \in Hom_{R}(N_{2}, M)$.

If Im right, I need to prove that if $M$ is quasi-injective, then for $f:N_{1} \to M$ linear morphism and $i: N_{1} \to N_{2}$ the inclusion, we need to show the existence of a morphism $g:N_{2} \to M$ such that $f=gi$ ?

I cant see neither of both implications. My guess is that probably Im misunderstanding what I need to prove.  Any suggestion would be truely apprecciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to understand the statement correctly. The idea is that the condition that every homomorphism $f : N_1 \to M$ extends to a homomorphism $N_2 \to M$ is equivalent to the statement that $f$ extends to an endomorphism on $M$, because we can simply restrict this endomorphism to get an extension on every submodule of $M$ containing $N_1$. Here's a sketch of the argument.

Suppose that $M$ is quasi-injective. Use quasi-injectivity on the inclusion $i : N_1 \hookrightarrow M$ to conclude that a homomorphism $f : N_1 \to M$ extends to an endomorphism of $M$ (this is sufficient to get the desired claim).

Now for the converse, let $f : N \to M$ be injective and $g : N \to M$ be a homomorphism. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $N$ is a submodule of $M$, and that $f = i$ is the inclusion of $N$ into $M$ (why?). By assumption, you can extend $g$ to an endomorphism $h$ on $M$. In other words,
$$ g = hi = hf.$$